# how to list Google Cloud SQL instances in the deleting state?

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to build automation around Cloud SQL and one of the really painful issues is that the API doesn't seem to list *all* existing instances.

For example, if I delete an instance A, then list all instances A is not in the list, but if I then try to create a fresh A I get a 409 error which basically reveals the fact that A still exists in a deleting state but I just can't see it.

Is there a way to list *all* instances including the deleting ones, and if not then why not?

Answer (score 1):

Not at this time.

Can you tell me a little bit more about why you want to see a list of deleted instances? I do not expect adding this functionality will happen any time soon, but if you could let me know the use case then maybe there's a good solution that doesn't involve listing at the API level.

Comment: And you can't reuse the instance name for 30 days anyway, so this wouldn't help. I suggest appending a date to a base name.

Comment: A good API would list the instances that are in the deleting state, simply for the sake of completeness and transparency. What is the argument to hide them?

Comment: The use-case is automatic provisioning of applications using a system similar to Google Deployment Manager. When redeploying an app it's impossible to know up-front whether it will succeed o not. Yes, I can append a random string to everything, but that ends up also being awkward in other ways.